# How to convert this scheduled script into the mapreduce script

Tags: suitescript2.0

I want to convert this script into the mapReduce Script.

Actually I used api in this script so I am not able to pass value in other functions like map or reduce.

so I want to put all order information in reduce stage & perform the action like custom record createion,sales order creation.

Give me the proper example in that they uses the api and perform different operations.

Otherwise tell me the logic How I can write this script into the MapReduce script.

and please note the point I used dataflow1 function using that function I am fetching the data of 2 store using mirkal api so I want to write this function also in the mapReduce script.

I have a confusion please give me the answer.

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
 define(['N/http', 'N/https', 'N/record', 'N/search', 'N/error','N/encode','N/query','N/format'],
 function(http, https, record, search,error,encode,query,format) {
    function execute(context) {
        // var storeId;
        function dataflowfirst(store_Name,store_id)
        {
    
          try
          {
              var mirkalUrl ='https://' + store_Name + '.mirakl.net/api/orders';
              var headers = {
                    'Authorization':'d9e04f3b-7b2a-473b-bab1-619e7d49ff25',
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    'Accept':'*/*'
                  };

              var response = https.get({
                url: mirkalUrl,
                headers: headers
              });
              var responseBody = response.body;
              var orders = JSON.parse(responseBody);
              var customRecordIdsToUpdate = " ";
              for(var ord = 0;ord < orders.orders.length ; ord++) ///due to the orderstatus 
              {
 
                var orderOneByOne = JSON.stringify(orders.orders[ord]);
                var orderState = orders.orders[ord].order_state;
                var orderId = orders.orders[ord].order_id;
                var created_date = orders.orders[ord].created_date;
                var originalDate =  created_date.substring(0, 10);
                var parts = originalDate.split('-');
                var formattedDate = parts[1] + '/' + parts[2] + '/' + parts[0]; 
                var newDate = new Date(formattedDate);

                 var rec = record.create({type: 'customrecord_mirkal_request_response',isDynamic:true});
                 rec.setValue({fieldId: 'custrecord_mirkal_request_body',value: mirkalUrl});
                 rec.setValue({ fieldId: 'custrecord_mirkal_store2_response', value: orderOneByOne});
                 rec.setValue({ fieldId: 'custrecord_mirkal_ns_flow', value: '2'});
                 rec.setValue({fieldId: 'custrecord_mirkal_request_headers',value: JSON.stringify(headers)});
                 rec.setValue({fieldId: 'custrecord_mirkal_id',value: orderId});
                 var customRecordId = rec.save();
                 log.debug('customrecordId',customRecordId);
                 customRecordIdsToUpdate =customRecordId; 
                 
                if(orderState == 'SHIPPING')
                {
                    var salesOrder = record.create({type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, isDynamic: false});
                    var soDate = salesOrder.setValue({
                                fieldId: 'trandate',
                                value: newDate
                            });
                    var customerName = salesOrder.setValue({
                                fieldId: 'entity',
                                value: "3595"
                            });
                    
                    var status = salesOrder.setValue({
                                fieldId: 'orderstatus',
                                value: "B" 
                            });
                  
                    var memoField = salesOrder.setValue({
                                fieldId: 'memo',
                                value: "SO Created successfully"
                            });
                    
                    var orderIdOfMirkal = salesOrder.setValue({
                        fieldId: 'custbody_mirkal_order_id',
                        value: orderId
                    });
                  
                    var mirkalStore = salesOrder.setValue({
                        fieldId: 'custbody_mirkal_store',
                        value: store_id
                    });
                   
                    var lineData = orders.orders[ord].order_lines;

                    var n=0;
                    for(var orderLine = 0;orderLine < lineData.length;orderLine ++ ) //3
                    {
                        var itemDetails = lineData[orderLine];
                        var productSku = itemDetails.product_sku;
                     
                        var inventoryitemSearchObj = search.create({
                        type: "inventoryitem",
                        filters:
                        [
                            ["type","anyof","InvtPart"],
                            "AND",
                            ["name","is",productSku]
                        ],
                        columns:
                        [
                            search.createColumn({
                                name: "itemid",
                                sort: search.Sort.ASC,
                                label: "Name"
                            }),
                            search.createColumn({name: "itemid", sort: search.Sort.ASC,label: "Name"}),
                            search.createColumn({name: "custitem5", label: "Item SKU"}),
                            search.createColumn({name: "internalid", label: "Internal ID"})
                        ]
                        });

                        var searchResultCount = inventoryitemSearchObj.run().getRange({
                            start: 0,
                            end: 1000
                        });
                        //log.debug('searchResultCount',searchResultCount);

                         
                       
                        for(var i = 0; i < searchResultCount.length; i++)
                        {
                           if (searchResultCount[i].getValue({ name: "itemid",label: "itemid"}) === productSku)
                           {
                              var internalId = searchResultCount[i].getValue({ name: "internalid", label: "Internal ID" });
                              log.debug('id',internalId);

                              salesOrder.setSublistValue({
                                sublistId: 'item',
                                fieldId: 'item',
                                line: orderLine ,
                                value: internalId
                            });
                           }
                        
                            n++;
                       }
                      
                       

                        salesOrder.setSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'item',
                            fieldId: 'quantity',
                            line:orderLine,
                            value: itemDetails.quantity
                        });

                
                        salesOrder.setSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'item',
                            fieldId: 'rate',
                            line:orderLine,
                            value: itemDetails.price_unit
                        });
                       
                        salesOrder.setSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'item',
                            fieldId: 'custcol_mirkal_order_line_id',
                            line:orderLine,
                            value: itemDetails.order_line_id
                        });
                }
               var salesOrderInternalId = salesOrder.save();
               log.debug('salesOrderInternalId',salesOrderInternalId);
                
                if(salesOrderInternalId)
                {
                    var updateCustomRecord = record.submitFields({
                    type: 'customrecord_mirkal_request_response',
                    id: customRecordIdsToUpdate,
                    values: {
                                'custrecord_sales_order_reference': salesOrderInternalId,
                                'custrecord_mirkal_response_code': "201",
                                'custrecord_mirkal_stores': store_id
                            }
                    }); 
                    log.debug('updateCustomRecord',updateCustomRecord);
                 }
                 break;
                 
               }
             }
            }
            catch(e)
            { 
                log.error({
                    title: e.name,
                    details: e.toString()
                });

                var updateCustomRecord1 = record.submitFields({
                type: 'customrecord_mirkal_request_response',
                id: customRecordIdsToUpdate,
                values: {
                            'custrecord_mirkal_store2_response': e.toString(),
                            'custrecord_mirkal_response_code': "400"
                        }
                }); 
      
              } 
             

            }
            for (var index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    var store = 'macysus-preprod';
                    var storeId = '1';
                    try {
                        dataflowfirst(store,storeId);
      
                    } catch (error) {
                      log.debug('error',error)
                    }
                }
                if (index == 1) {
                    var store = 'macysus-preprod';
                    var storeId = '2';
                    try {
                        dataflowfirst(store,storeId);
      
                    } catch (error) {
                      log.debug('error',error)
                    }
                }
            }
       }
                                
         return {
             execute: execute
         };
     });
```